# CharacterBody2D Sliding out of StaticBody2D instead of teleporting out of it in GODOT 4.1

Tags: game-physics, collision, godot, gdscript, godot4

I am trying to replicate Mario Maker's On/Off switches and if the player got stuck inside the block after it was toggled on, the player just teleported out it. I know this is expected, but I wanted a smoother transition. After looking it up, I found a video replicating the same feature in Godot, but the player, when stuck inside the block, slid out it, much more smoothly. How can I go about doing that?

This is the [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MR6JR_lUF7M&list=LL&index=6&ab_channel=Mahdi%2a2007) I'm referencing above - on the second 33:

I tried disabling collisions when inside the block, but the Engine disabled it after abruptly moving outside the it; Tried manipulating only the sprite with a Tween, but like the collision, it happened after getting out of the block.